# JasperReports and missing fonts on Windows

Tags: jasper-reports

Our applications uses *JasperReports.3.7.1* and runs on *Windows*. One of our sites is unable to print their reports. This message appears in the log:

```
Font 'Arial' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details
```

This file is present: `c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf.`

Why can't JVM or *JasperReports* find it?

Using **`net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font`** allows the report to print but is not a good solution.

Most of the info I've found so far in regards to `Font 'Arial' is not available to the JVM.` refers to migrating reports from *Windows* to flavors of *Unix* which isn't the problem encountered here.

Thanks for any suggestions, ideas or insights

Comment: Did you use the [Font Extensions mechanism](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions)

Comment: You can use a fonts that exists in both Linux and Windows, like *Serif*, or you can do what @AlexK said.

Comment: arial works at all of our other sites. The font is on the system as we have c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf. Any ideas as to why arial isn't working on this site?